# Deleting core data element at specific position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to delete the selected core data element in my table view when the "edit" then the "delete" button is pressed. I can't seem to do this though.
My very last method is where the deleting should go. That method being successfully called when delete button is pressed but I keep getting the error "no visible @interface at "WebBrowser" declares the selector "deleteObject"

Here is part of my code.

```
#import "WebTableViewController2.h"

#import "WebBrowser.h"
#import CoreData/CoreData.h 
#import "EditViewController.h"

@interface WebTableViewController2 ()

@property UIManagedDocument *webDocument;
@property NSFetchedResultsController *resultsController;
@end

@implementation WebTableViewController2

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *fileName = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"WebDB.db"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: fileName];
    self.webDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:fileURL];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName])
    {
        [self.webDocument saveToURL:fileURL forSaveOperation: UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
         {
             if(!success) NSLog(@" Database creation failed");
             [self fetchData];
         }];
    }else
    {
        [self.webDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success)
         {
             if(!success) NSLog(@" Database opening failed");
             [self fetchData];
         }];
    }


}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;    
}

- (void) fetchData
{

    NSFetchRequest *request= [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"WebBrowser"];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name1" ascending:YES]];
    self.resultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:
                              self.webDocument.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:Nil cacheName:Nil];

    self.resultsController.delegate = self;

    /*
     NSError *error = nil;
     NSUInteger count = [self.webDocument.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
     //[request release];
     NSLog(@"this is the number in data base: %i", count);
     */

    NSError *error = nil;

    if([self.resultsController performFetch: &error]){
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Could not fetch data: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }

}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //deleting goes here
    NSLog(@"deleting");
    WebBrowser *webBrowser = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [webBrowser deleteObjectat:indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: You probably did that on purpose, and I am not in front of a Mac to try, but shouldn't `#import CoreData/CoreData.h` be `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You have to delete you managedObject but in your source code you are not doing so.
[_context deleteObject:webBrowser];

Answer (score 0):

```
[webBrowser deleteObjectat:indexPath.row];
```

should probably be

```
[context deleteObject:webBrowser];
```

where `context` is your managed object context.

Comment: isnt my managed object context "webDocument" ive declared that at the top. that doesnt seem to work though.

Comment: this is what i have and it doesnt work.                        WebBrowser *webBrowser = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [webDocument deleteObject:webBrowser];

Comment: @MesbahJamali: Your managed object context seems to be `self.webDocument.managedObjectContext`, so it should be `WebBrowser *webBrowser = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; [self.webDocument.managedObjectContext deleteObject:webBrowser]`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R that worked but when i close the app and reopen it the deleted items re-appear. Sorry im a complete Noob

Comment: @MesbahJamali: Do you *save* the document after changes?

Comment: yep, i just added this bit of code [self.webDocument.managedObjectContext save:&error]; still doesnt work though

Comment: @MesbahJamali: I have some experience with Core Data, but not so much with UIManagedDocument. According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11440518/1187415, the document should be saved automatically if the app goes into background. - Or did you *kill* the app, e.g. by stopping it in the Xcode debugger? Then of course changes are not saved.

Answer (score 0):

The way i did it is inside of `commitEditingStyle`

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {


        Entity *loopEntity = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        // Delete the managed object at the given index path.
    NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.context deleteObject:eventToDelete];

        // Update the array and table view.
    [self.tableArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.ammoTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        // Commit the change.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.context save:&error]) {
            // Handle the error.
    }
}
```